# c++ call private function in container class

Tags: c++, container-classes

If I have two classes:

```
class worker
{
   Top *mp_parent;

   worker(Top *parent) : mp_parent(parent) {};

   int doSomeWork()
   {
      int i = mp_parent->privateFunction(); // This is the function I want to call
   }
}

class Top
{
   private:
   worker m_Worker;

   int privateFunction() {return 1;}

}
```

Where Top class contains a instance of worker class. When worker is instantiated, a pointer to the parent class is passed in.
Later, the function doSomeWork() is called which needs to get a value from the parent, so it calls mp_parent->privateFunction().

What is the best way to achieve this? - I don't really want to make privateFunction() a public function if I can avoid it, but it does not work as it is because it is private :o

Are there any other options?

Comment: Make Top a friend of worker. Alternatively, make worker a nested class in Top.

Comment: first eliminate the circular dependency.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes, sorry, this is only a minimal example I have not taken any care about other things then to describe the problem :)

Comment: Why not just register a callback in the worker function instead of the actual parent's address?

Comment: @NeilKirk, oooh yes, this will work nicely thanks :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How would you rewrite this?

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. worker should be a friend of Top.

Comment: @NeilKirk that's ok, I figured that :)  ... also to fix my "example code" I would use a forward declare and put the implementation into c files and...etc... but its too long winded and serves little point for my question :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the 'friend' keyword:

```
class worker
{
   Top *mp_parent;

   worker(Top *parent) : mp_parent(parent) {};

   int doSomeWork()
   {
      int i = mp_parent->privateFunction(); // This is the function I want to call
   }
}

class Top
{
   friend class worker;
   private:
   worker m_Worker;

   int privateFunction() {return 1;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use of friends:

```
class Top
{
   private:
   friend class Worker;
   worker m_Worker;

   int privateFunction() {return 1;}

}
```

You should be thoughtful about making friends, and consider whether you can redesign to avoid them, but sometimes it makes sense.